# How to delete object oriented function in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to delete object oriented function in java script.

I need to delete blockOne and all its properties but I don't know how to.
I'm making a sort of 2d survival and need to be able to break blocks.
If there is another way to do this, I would be glad try it.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

window.onload = setIntervel(Draw, 60/100);

function Block(x, y){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.width = 100;
this.height = 100;
this.draw = function(){
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

}

let blockOne = new Block(200, 200);

function Draw(){
blockOne.draw()
}
```

Comment: `blockOne = undefined`?

Comment: What do you mean by "object oriented function"?